# How to print JSON data to the console only after fetch in React Native?

Tags: json, react-native, fetch-api

I have tried the following code:

```
const response =await fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json');
const json= await response.json();
console.log(json.result);
```

to print fetched JSON data to the console but it's not working. How can I write fetched data directly to console?

Comment: await is used with a promise. You can get to log after you resolve the promise.

Comment: There is an issue with your code. I’ve demonstrated a solution below. However asking about using the data to create a view should be a separate question, as it’s unrelated to your code sample.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An answer using sync/await (which you were using in your question)

```
const fetchAndLog = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json');
    const json = await response.json();
    // just log ‘json’
    console.log(json);
}

fetchAndLog();
```

Comment: I will not print at all if the response is not a valid JSON (eg server failure)

Answer (score 6):

```
fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
    console.log(responseJson);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using this way it is working fine.

```
fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')  
 .then((response) => response.text())
 .then((responseText) => {
     console.log(JSON.parse(responseText));
 })
 .catch((error) => {
     console.log("reset client error-------",error);
});
```

Below is used for particular method request. Headers and Body are used for send data to server. For this way we can request type and method for fetch function.

```
      fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST', 
            timeout:10000,
            headers: headers,
            body: JSON.stringify(params) 
        })  
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((responseText) => {
             console.log(JSON.parse(responseText));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
             console.log("reset client error-------",error);
        });
    });
```

Comment: It is working fine. Thank you for giving detail about requestType or Method used in fetch operation.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is the right way to write :

```
async function fetchblogEntry(){
    const response=await fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json');
    console.log(response.json())
}

fetchblogEntry()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using JSON.stringify function as well

```
fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/username`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(setdata);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```